# Mounting volumes to a Kali Linux docker container stops interactive bash shell aesthetic features?

Tags: bash, docker

When running my Kali Linux docker container `headerless-kali-linux` without mounting volumes using the command:

```
docker run --rm -it headerless-kali-linux
```

The bash terminal within the container has colours and aesthetic features, which I want. They look like this:

[image: Aesthetic features]

However, when I mount my volumes to the container with the command:

```
docker run --rm -it -v %cd%\root:/root -v %cd%\postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql headerless-kali-linux
```

The aesthetic features go, as if volumes should somehow affect that, and I'm left with plain bash in my terminal. If anyone has any idea why this is happening, please let me know! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why this is happening

You are mounting `/root` so you are overwriting shell startup files, that could set up the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be fixed when creating docker volumes as opposed to using a local source in the C drive. You can also create a container first, not remove it, see its ID with `docker ps -a` and then populate local directories with `docker cp <container ID>:/path/to/dir /path/to/local/volume`. From here you can attach the volumes to the local sources with the `-v /path/to/local/volume:/path/to/dir` option when running.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).